# Which site should I ask a question regarding toys?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question regarding toys and toy manufacturing, specifically barbie dolls, but I do not know which Stack Exchange site to post it on. Which site is suitable for me?

My question is basically:

> How has barbie developed from being a local product to a global one and what the process of commodification for toy fashion dolls is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a site yet that supports your kind of question. Also, I can't find any site that is related to product development, or product lifecycles, or toys in general. (maybe the very broad ['Business' proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74347/business))

It seems that you either have to propose a site that would eventually answer that question, or find some off-site resource to do so.

Just a site note: your question seems quite broad to me, possibly even 'primarily opinion based', both close reasons on all sites, although I am not an expert in the subject.

Comment: Maybe in the future someone will propose such a site, but for now, I've found some relevant information. Thank you for the answer.